# OpenMPI in SGE fails when not observed

Tags: linux, cluster, gridengine

I know the topic is weird but so is my problem. On our cluster we have SGE with OpenMPI compiled for tight integration. When I set it up it worked just fine in my tests and so far there have been no complaints until recently. Thing is: When I submit a job using the OpenMPI PE and run my binary using mpirun it fails.

The error messages are like

`fully.quallified.host.name - daemon did not report back when launched` and

`[hostname:\d{5}] [[63730,0],\d{1,2}] routed:binomial: Connection to lifeline [[63730,0],0] lost`

thats even for something simple like `mpirun -np 40 --pernode hostname`

now here's the weird part: if I turn on verbose output for plm_base it works: `mpirun -np 40 --mca plm_base_verbose 5 --pernode hostname` does work!!! The loads of debuging output this produces on stderr don't contain any indication of a problem whatsoever.

I've tried this multiple times and I can always reproduce this so I'm quite positive that this isn't just a fluke. Problem is: I'm quite puzzled now.

I certainly miss something, so here's the questions:

1. Does setting the verbosity in this case also silently set other parameters?
2. What else could cause this weird behaviour?

Best Regards.

Edit: configuration of relevant PE:

```
pe_name           ompi-gcc
slots             2000
user_lists        NONE
xuser_lists       NONE
start_proc_args   /bin/true
stop_proc_args    /bin/true
allocation_rule   $round_robin
control_slaves    TRUE
job_is_first_task FALSE
urgency_slots     min
```

Nothing fancy there... OpenMPI is compiled for thight integration and detects everything it needs... Nevertheless it doesn't work with qrsh i.e. it only works when disabling qrsh for rsh...

Comment: Can you include your parallel environment configuration?

Comment: here you are... nothing fancy, really

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. After some trial and error with the other parameters of `plm` I found that setting `plm_rsh_disable_qrsh` fixes the problem. However that doesn't explain why setting its base verbosity to something other than 0 also fixed the problem. This is the part I still don't get.